# Pandas: convert column to list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
date    member_id   val
2016-06-01  2377264 14
2016-06-01  289719  6
2016-06-02  289719  12
2016-06-02  2377264 1
2016-06-03  289719  0
2016-06-04  289719  0
2016-06-05  289719  3
```

I need to get 
    member_id   val
    2377264   [14, 1]
    289719    [6, 12, 0, 3]
And next I want to sum elements in list and if there is 0 in list, write it. I mean

```
member_id   val
2377264   [15]
289719    [18, 0, 0, 3]
```

I tried

```
vals = []
print df.groupby('member_id')['val'].apply(lambda x: vals.append(x))
```

but it returns all None values in a column.
How can I fix that?

Comment: I don't understand why you sum the elements sometimes and you create a list others?

Comment: @erip I need to sum from the first elem that isn't equal to 0 to last elem that isn't equal to 0. If a have `1, 2, 5, 0, 3,2, 6, 7, 45, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 34` I need to get `8, 0, 63, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 34`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

## 1. if you want val list

```
df.groupby('member_id')['val'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
```

**output**

```
member_id
289719     [6, 12, 0, 0, 3]
2377264             [14, 1]
Name: val, dtype: object
```

## 2. To get list of list

```
df.groupby('member_id')['val'].apply(lambda x: list(x)).tolist()
```

**output**

```
[[6, 12, 0, 0, 3], [14, 1]]
```

## 3. To get dict

```
df.groupby('member_id')['val'].apply(lambda x: list(x)).to_dict()
```

**output**

```
{2377264: [14, 1], 289719: [6, 12, 0, 0, 3]}
```

## 4. To get sum

```
df.groupby('member_id')['val'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))
```

**output**

```
member_id
289719     21
2377264    15
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

## 5. Get Sum of numbers between zero's

As per your comment you need to get a list of vals and sum elements between 0's and to do that you should use bellow code

```
def sumNumberBetweenZero(values):
    valsum=[0]
    for i in values:
      if i==0:
        if valsum[-1]!=0:valsum.append(0)
        valsum.append(0)
      valsum[-1]+=i
    return valsum
```

### 5.A. get sum of all elements

```
sumNumberBetweenZero(df["val"].tolist())
```

**output**

```
[33L, 0, 0L, 3L]
```

### 5.B. get sum of values groupby `member_id`

```
df.groupby('member_id')['val'].apply(lambda x: sumNumberBetweenZero((x))
```

**output**

```
member_id
289719     [18, 0, 0, 3]
2377264             [15]
Name: val, dtype: object
```

## 5.iii. For the list given as example

```
sumNumberBetweenZero([1, 2, 5, 0, 3,2, 6, 7, 45, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 34])
```

**output**

```
[8, 0, 63, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 34]
```

Comment: I don't understand. This doesn't accomplish OP's goals.

Comment: What exactly you want to do

Comment: _I need to sum from the first elem that isn't equal to 0 to last elem that isn't equal to 0._

Comment: please add a question with proper details and share link

Comment: a) This isn't my question. b) The details both in the question and accompanying questions describe the problem _and_ give examples. This answer does not satisfy the examples.

Comment: I have added solution for those scenario that @petr-petrov mentioned in comment section