# pandas dataframe column has string with commas how to convert it to a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A column in a dataframe has values, `'abc,def,ghi'`. I want to make an array like this:`['abc','def','ghi']`

Comment: This gives much more detailed answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784200/pandas-convert-column-to-list

Answer (score 8):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.split(',')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['abc,def,ghi','abc,def,ghi']})
df['col'] = df['col'].str.split(',')
print (df)
               col
0  [abc, def, ghi]
1  [abc, def, ghi]

print (df.loc[0, 'col'])
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

print (type(df.loc[0, 'col']))
<class 'list'>
```

If never `NaN` values use list comprehension:

```
df['col'] = [x.split(',') for x in df['col'].values.tolist()]
print (df)
               col
0  [abc, def, ghi]
1  [abc, def, ghi]
```

Comment: But I want it like this ['abc','def','ghi']

Comment: Hmmm, do you need double `'` ? Because if strings, `'` is by default.

Comment: It works fine for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Aravindh don't forget to accept this answer and up vote if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `df` with random number of strings separated by commas.

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
k = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(list('ABCD,'), (k, 20))
).sum(1).str.strip(',').str.replace(',+', ',').to_frame('col1')
df

                   col1
0  ADCDCCDCDACAA,ACCA,B
1      DC,DDD,DBDA,CCAC
2    A,B,CCAC,DB,C,CD,D
3   ADDBAA,DA,BD,C,AACA
4   DADBB,D,DBD,ADCAADB
5  CBCBA,CA,B,AA,CDCBDB
6  BD,D,DDB,AC,B,C,ABBA
7  C,CABBBADCD,DBCC,ACD
8    CC,A,BCAAAACBBA,BD
9  AC,A,ADBBD,BDCCDDABD
```

I like to use `numpy`s functionality for splitting

```
df.assign(col1=np.core.defchararray.split(df.col1.values.astype(str), ','))

                           col1
0      [ADCDCCDCDACAA, ACCA, B]
1         [DC, DDD, DBDA, CCAC]
2    [A, B, CCAC, DB, C, CD, D]
3     [ADDBAA, DA, BD, C, AACA]
4      [DADBB, D, DBD, ADCAADB]
5    [CBCBA, CA, B, AA, CDCBDB]
6  [BD, D, DDB, AC, B, C, ABBA]
7     [C, CABBBADCD, DBCC, ACD]
8       [CC, A, BCAAAACBBA, BD]
9     [AC, A, ADBBD, BDCCDDABD]
```

---

***Fast for small data***

```
%timeit df.assign(col1=np.core.defchararray.split(df.col1.values.astype(str), ','))
1000 loops, best of 3: 204 µs per loop

%timeit df.assign(col1=df['col1'].str.split(','))
1000 loops, best of 3: 327 µs per loop

%timeit df.assign(col1=[x.split(',') for x in df['col1'].values.tolist()])
1000 loops, best of 3: 210 µs per loop
```

***Not as fast for large dataa***

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
k = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(list('ABCD,'), (k, 100))
).sum(1).str.strip(',').str.replace(',+', ',').to_frame('col1')

%timeit df.assign(col1=np.core.defchararray.split(df.col1.values.astype(str), ','))
10 loops, best of 3: 19.6 ms per loop

%timeit df.assign(col1=df['col1'].str.split(','))
100 loops, best of 3: 13.5 ms per loop

%timeit df.assign(col1=[x.split(',') for x in df['col1'].values.tolist()])
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop
```